Deploy laravel 9 on ionos apache2 Ubuntu 22.04.4
your text
I'm trying to deploy a laravel site on ionos VPS. When i launch my site on the browser, i've got this error:
your text
My .htaccess:

# enable gzip compressing for the following mime-types
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/shtml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

### IMPORTANT ###
### Because we can't change the webroot folder to a subfolder of the document root, we need this rewrite rules ###

RewriteEngine on

# serve existing files in the /public folder as if they were in /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]

# route everything else to /public/index.php
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]

your text
**
On the browser:**
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
On the error.log:
ModSecurity: Output filter: Response body too large (over limit of 1048576, total not specified).  [uri "/index.php"]
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 298910] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available):  AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (passing brigade to output filters)
your text

Please take a look at the documentation, especially the SecResponseBodyLimit.
The default value is 524288 (bytes).
I suggest to increase that, may be it's enough to do that in the affected VHOST.
The syntax is:
SecResponseBodyLimit 2097152

where the new value is twice as the assumed current limit.
